# Convergence of general Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

For any $a,h \in \mathbb{R}$, how can we see the series,
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} h^k$ converges to $f(a+h)$?

Comment: In general, it does not. The convergence depends on what $f$ is. The key word is *analytic function* (or *real-analytic*, to distinguish from complex analysis). Do you have a specific $f$ in mind?

Comment: if we think, $f(x)=\dfrac{A+B}{2} e^{x} + \dfrac{A-B}{2} e^{-x}$ where $f(0)=A$ and $f^{'}(0)=B$

Comment: You may want to edit this information into the post. Also, the answer still depends on how "$e^x$" is defined. Under one common definition, $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$, so the Taylor series converges to exponential function by definition.

Answer (score 2):

A standard counterexample is $f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-{1 \over x^2}}, & x \neq 0 \\ 0, & x=0 \end{cases}$. The Taylor coefficients around $x=0$ are all zero, but the function is clearly not zero.

(Note that this has nothing to do with the radius of convergence of the terms ${ f^{(k)}(a) \over k!}$, as in this case, all of these terms are zero.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ equals it's taylor series. Then $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^k(a) (x-a)^k}{k!} $$ and then performing the substitution $x \to x+h$ followed by $x \to a$ yields the formula you ask about.

As others have pointed out there are convergence issues, in general.